# Eliminar duplicados según cantidad de información por fila en una base de encuesta, utilizando R

Tags: r

tengo una base de datos de respuestas a una encuesta. Sucede que existen varias respuestas de las mismas personas, cada respuesta está enlazada a un identificador como número único (DNI, por ejemplo) por lo cual se puede filtrar según ID duplicado. El problema es que existen casos donde personas respondieron 3 veces y de esas respuestas me interesa la que tenga más cantidad de columnas completadas (lo que equivale a respuestas completas).

Estoy analizando en R esta base, por lo cual agradecería si me pudieran orientar para obtener el resultado que busco o ver como identificar de forma clara las filas que deseo para quedarme.
Este df sirve de ejemplo:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~a,~b,  ~c,  ~d,  ~e,
    "a", 2,  3,  NA,   1, 
    "a", 2,  3,  "SI", 4, 
    "a", 1,  NA, "NO", NA, 
    "b", NA, 2,  "SI", NA, 
    "b", NA, 3,  "NO", 2, 
    "b", NA, 2,  NA,   2, 
    "c", 1,  2,  "SI", NA, 
    "c", NA, NA, NA,   2
     )
```

Quisiera saber como identificar y quedarme con la b(index 5), a (index 2) y c (index 7) teniendo en cuenta el criterio de que son las alternativas con mayor numero de respuestas completas de las mismas personas (suponiendo que la letra es el identificador)

````
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  a         b     c     d     e
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         2     3     NA     1
2 a         2     3    "SI"    4
3 a         1    NA    "NO"    NA
4 b        NA     2    "SI"    NA
5 b        NA     3    "NO"    2
6 b        NA     2     NA     2
7 c         1     2    "SI"    NA
8 c        NA    NA     NA     2
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución con tidyverse seria así:

```
df %>%
  mutate(n_respuestas = rowSums(!is.na(select(.,!a)))) %>% 
  arrange(a, desc(n_respuestas)) %>%
  distinct(a, .keep_all = T)
```

1. Crear la variable n_respuestas para contar el numero de columnas distintas a la columna "a" que no sean NA, es decir, contengan respuesta.
2. Ordenar por el identificar, en este caso "a" y el numero de respuestas de mayor a menor.
3. Eliminar duplicados, ya que al tener ordenados los datos, preservaremos la fila con mayor cantidad de respuestas

Finalmente puedes eliminar la columna auxiliar n_respuestas añadiendo un

```
select(-n_respuestas)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  a         b     c d         e
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 a         2     3 SI        4
2 b        NA     3 NO        2
3 c         1     2 SI       NA
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó!